# Why does this query take all day to run on mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that takes several minutes to run on mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM
  sys_quote_master AS g1
JOIN (SELECT order_id, order_base_id, max(order_date_last_revised) as mostrecent 
  FROM sys_quote_master group by order_base_id) AS g2
ON g2.mostrecent = g1.order_date_last_revised
ORDER BY g1.order_id;
```

The query runs for several minutes and eventually I get this error:

> Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_4f0_1.MYI'; try to repair it

Can someone please help me and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Who knows? Post your schema as well please.

Comment: It may help if you put a limit on the dates retrieved and examine the rows returned to ensure they are what you expect. Also, test the subquery separately to ensure it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you EXPLAIN PLAN, I think you'll see that the inner SELECT has to do a TABLE SCAN to find the max(order_date_last_revised).

I wonder if the subselect would be faster if you used a GROUP BY and HAVING?

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/GROUPandHAVINGwithsubquery.htm

Ask EXPLAIN PLAN to tell you if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but try to change the query to

```
SELECT *
FROM sys_quote_master g3
WHERE (g3.order_id, g3.order_base_id) IN (
    SELECT g2.order_id, g2.order_base_id
    FROM sys_quote_master g2
    group by order_id, order_base_id
    having max(order_date_last_revised) = (
        select g1.order_date_last_revised
        from sys_quote_master g1
        where g2.order_id = g1.order_id
        and g2.order_base_id = g1.order_base_id
    )
);
```

This is assuming you have an indexed unique key at (order_id, order_base_id), also.. maybe you will need to change

```
having max(order_date_last_revised) = (
```

to

```
having max(order_date_last_revised) IN (
```

hope it helps